# SQL - Select one instance of grouped rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window

I have a query where rows are grouped. Multiple rows where the product ID are the same but where date and quantity differs, are grouped so I can calculate the sum of quantities, average prices, etc.

I now need to add the date when the last sale occurred and the corresponding quantity. I added the date with MAX(date), but how do I add the corresponding quantity?

I use MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Example query:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(quantity) as 'Total q',
       AVG(price) as 'Avg price',
       MAX(price) as 'Max price',
       MAX(date) as 'Last sale date'
FROM table
WHERE date > 2018
GROUP BY id
```

Original sample data:

```
id     quantity    price     date
1      20          2.30      2018-6-2
1      10          2.40      2018-6-4
1      5           2.55      2018-6-10
2      15          12.50     2018-5-20
2      100         7.50      2018-6-1
2      50          10.00     2018-6-12
```

Expected result:

```
id    total q    avg price   max price   last sale    last q  last p
1     35         2.42        2.55        2018-6-10    5       2.55
2     165        10.00       12.50       2018-6-12    50      10.00
```

Comment: If `GROUP BY id` id is PK or UNIQUE then simplyu `MIN(quantity)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as fomatted text, not images.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda but wouldn't this just simply return the minimum value of quantity? its possible that this minimum value is not the most recent sale

Comment: @A.T. As I said, if you `group by PK`. Please post your real query + define RDBMS that you use. If it is Oracle you could use `KEEP` clause.

Comment: The quantity for the most recent sale.. Would require you to rejoin back to the table - you may have two sales on that date.. Not sure what format your dates are in.. Does it have something like an ISO Timestamp too?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i edited my post for sample data, expected result and dbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `windowed functions`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
       SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as "Total q",
       AVG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as "Avg price",
       MAX(price) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as "Max price",
       MAX(_date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as "Last sale date",
       FIRST_VALUE(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY _date DESC) AS last_q,
       FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY _date DESC) AS last_p
FROM tab
WHERE _date > '2018-01-01';
```

Output:

```
┌────┬─────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ id │ Total q │ Avg price │ Max price │   Last sale date    │ last_q │ last_p │
├────┼─────────┼───────────┼───────────┼─────────────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│  1 │      35 │  2.416666 │      2.55 │ 10/06/2018 00:00:00 │      5 │   2.55 │
│  2 │     165 │ 10.000000 │     12.50 │ 12/06/2018 00:00:00 │     50 │  10.00 │
└────┴─────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4560a8e2eb171f5aa316998814437335)**

Comment: Thanks! In reality, I have more columns (than only ID) that I select and group by, e.g.  'region' and 'description'. how would this change the query?

Comment: @A.T. . . . You would add them to the `partition by` columns -- and include them in the `select`.

Comment: @A.T. In that case please accept the answer by clicking the check sign to the left of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

make use of a variable, where you can set the corresponding quantity, may be similar kind of

```
DECLARE @LastSaleQty AS int

SELECT id, @LastSaleQty = SUM(quantity)
FROM table
WHERE date = MAX(date)
GROUP BY id

SELECT id,
    SUM(quantity) as 'Total q',
    AVG(price) as 'Avg price',
    MAX(price) as 'Max price',
    MAX(date) as 'Last sale date',
    @LastSaleQty As 'Last Sale Qty'
FROM table
WHERE date > 2018
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This won't work at all. `LastSaleQty` cannot hold multiple values.

Comment: When I posted the answer, the question was partial posted. After my answer the question was updated.

Comment: In that case you could either update or delete the answer. As it no longer answers the given question, it doesn't help future readers.