# Finding best work team based of their performance on previous assignments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to come up with a query to find the best workplace teammates based on how they did (together) on their previous assignments.

I have a `Work.Employee` table that I want to take the EmployeeID, match it with the `Work.EmployeeAssignment` table that contains the AssignmentID, and EmployeeID.
This AssignmentID references Work.Assignment to get the assignment dates.

The query should take the average time (StartingDate,EndingDate)on all assignments that these employees have done together.
Here is a snippet of what I have tried:

```
WITH MatesCTE(EmployeeID,AssignmentID, EmployeeName)
AS
(
    SELECT E.EmployeeID, E2.AssignmentID, E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS EmployeeName
    FROM Work.Employee E
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT EA.AssignmentID, EA.EmployeeID,
        FROM Work.EmployeeAssignment EA
    ) E2 ON E.EmployeeID = E2.EmployeeID GROUP BY E.EmployeeID, E2.AssignmentID, E.FirstName, E.LastName HAVING COUNT(E2.AssignmentID) > 1
)
SELECT M.EmployeeID, M.AssignmentID, M.EmployeeName,
AVG(DATEDIFF(y, A.StartingDate, A.EndingDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY M.TaskID) AS AverageTime
FROM MatesCTE M
INNER JOIN Work.Assignment A ON M.AssignmentID = A.AssignmentID
GROUP BY M.EmployeeID, M.AssignmentID, A.StartingDate, A.EndingDate, EmployeeName 
ORDER BY AverageTime, AssignmentID
```

Actual Result:
The average here is calculated on the same assignment instead of all shared assignments.

```
EmployeeID AssignmentID  EmployeeName      AverageTime
4            2           Employee1 E1LastName  0   
4            3           Employee1 E1LastName  6   
5            3           Employee2 E2LastName  6    
4            1           Employee1 E1LastName 14  
5            1           Employee2 E2LastName 14
```

Expected:

1. Only one instance of AssignmentID where both Employee1 and Employee2 were part of.
2. No one person assignments
3. The average time is the time on all the assignments that Employee1 and Employee2 were part of.

```
EmployeeID AssignmentID EmployeeName      AverageTime 
4            3          Employee1 E1LastName  10   
5            3          Employee2 E2LastName  10
```

Where the starting data here are the same as the actual result.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: Need sample starting data in addition to expected results.

Comment: A similar question that covers what i am trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812924/sql-select-one-instance-of-grouped-rows